# Sign in With google or facebook is not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, facebook-login, google-signin

I am currently working on a project in Laravel. The sign in with Facebook and Google is not working for me. the redirect function is working but the Callback function is not working. I am attaching my works. Please suggest me something to do . When i click login with facebook or google it successfully redirect me to facebook /google page and after login the callback function is not working . It says Error 403 , Access forbidden.

```
/this is my Route/

    Route::get('/auth/facebook', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
    Route::get('/auth/facebook/callback','SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
    Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthGoogleController@redirect');
    Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthGoogleController@callback');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');

/this is my Controller/

<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Socialite;
use Auth;
class SocialAuthGoogleController extends Controller
      {

    public function redirect()
                { 
                  return Socialite :: driver('google')->redirect();
                               }


    public function callback()
       {
        try {


            $googleUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
            $existUser = User::where('email',$googleUser->email)->first();


            if($existUser) {
                            Auth::loginUsingId($existUser->id);
                            }
            else {
                    $user = new User;
                    $user->name = $googleUser->name;
                    $user->email = $googleUser->email;
                    $user->google_id = $googleUser->id;
                    $user->password = md5(rand(1,10000));
                    $user->save();
                    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
                   }
                  return redirect()->to('/dashboard');

                    } 
            catch (Exception $e) {
                return 'error';
                                  }
           }
          }
/this is my database/

        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('provider');
        $table->string('provider_id')->unique();
        $table->string('google-id')->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/this is my service.php/



    'facebook' => [
            'client_id'     => '<omitted>',
            'client_secret' => '<omitted>',
            'redirect'      => 'https://shuffler.com/auth/facebook/callback'],
        'google' => [
            'client_id' => '<omitted>',
            'client_secret' => '<omitted>',
            'redirect' => 'https://shuffler.com/callback'],
```

Comment: Please confirm you've enabled the Google+ API from https://console.developers.google.com/apis

Comment: Yes i have . the redirect method is working . its redirecting me to google but after sign in the call back is not working